# Can I change the "settings" of my Mac computer remotely via ssh / remote login?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I'd like to be able to change settings on my remote computer, like power saving settings, etc. How can I do this via terminal?

Thanks!

Bonus question: will remote login via ssh wake the Mac if it is asleep, or in any way affect the sleep schedule (i.e. will activity through the shell count as wakeful activity as using the GUI directly would, sorry for the incorrect terminology)?

Comment: I'll have a play around with my macbook on your bonus q, but but first thoughts are: remote login could wake your mac if it's cabled and you have the wake on network access option selected. If it's on wifi, I don't believe it works, but never actually checked. And I don't *think* terminal commands will prevent sleep mode from occuring (it definitely doesn't stop dimming), but again, not something I've tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the former, sure. It depends on exactly what you want to change, but for example power settings can be accessed using the `pmset` command (e.g. `pmset sleep 20` to set your computer to sleep at 20 mins). Generally it's a case of working out what you want to change, and finding out the relevant shell command.